# Facet Name Based on the result in Solr

Tags: solr

I want to find the name of the facets out put based on the results i mean if i have the out put as

```
 <lst name="facet_fields">
   <lst name="state">
     <int name="kerala">3312</int>
     <int name="andaman">10</int>
     <int name="andhra">0</int>
     <int name="arunachal">0</int>
     <int name="assam">0</int>
    </lst>
    </lst>
```

i want the result of output as `kerala,andaman` as both of them having the `count > 0`
is there any possibility,please help me on this

Comment: you mean you want the output to be literally `kerala,andaman` ? comma separated?

Comment: @soulcheck no, i want that as output it can be any format not speciic with comma

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark the answer

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to specify the minimum count as 1 in your query. It can be achieved using [facet.mincount](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.mincount)